# Finding farthest item in an array with duplicates

Tags: algorithms, arrays, amortized-analysis

I have an array $A[]$ of size $L$, which contains numbers in the range $1 \ldots N$.  Here $L>N$, so the array will contain repetitions.  If $x,y$ are two numbers that are both present in the array, define the distance $d(x,y)$ to be the minimum difference in positions where $x,y$ appear, i.e.,

$$d(x,y) = \min \{|i-j| : A[i]=x, A[j]=y\}.$$

Given a number $x$ that is present in the array, I need to find the number $y$ in the array distance from $x$ is as large as possible.  In other words, given $x$, I am trying to find $y$ that makes $d(x,y)$ as large as possible (subject to the restriction that $y$ is a number in $A[]$).

Can this be done in $o(L)$ time per query?  It's OK to do some pre-processing of the array.

For example, suppose the array is $[1,3,2,3,4,5,3]$.  Then $d(5,3)=1$, since there is a $5$ one position away from a $3$ (a $5$ appears at index $5$ and a $3$ appears at index $6$).  If the query is $x=5$, the correct answer is $y=1$, since this makes the value of $d(5,y)$ as large as possible.

Comment: Solving for all queries takes $O(L)$ time by iterating over the array and keeping track of the minimum and maximum index of a given value of $k$. If the minimum is greater than the length of the array minus the maximum then use the first element of the input array, otherwise the last for a given value of $k$. After this preprocessing, queries require $O(1)$ time. Does that meet your criteria?

Comment: user2094963, for future reference, we'd like to see what you've tried and where you've gotten stuck in the question, and what research you've done.  Also, it often helps to include some motivation (what context did you encounter the problem in?).

Comment: @D.W. I was trying to reduce a tree problem into a linear structure, and the best i could do was find an O(n) solution for the above problem which was too slow.

Comment: @lewellen, your algorithm doesn't work.  Consider the array $[1,3,2,3,1,5,3]$.  Then given the query $5$, your algorithm will give the answer $1$, but that's not the correct answer: the correct answer is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a scheme that does $O(L \lg L)$ preprocessing, and thereafter lets you answer query for the value $x$ in $O(rN \lg L)$ time, where $r$ counts the number of times that $x$ is repeated.  This will be slightly more efficient than the naive algorithm for values $x$ that don't occur too many times in the array, but inefficient for common values.

Here's how.  During preprocessing, we're going to build a map $f$ defined by

$$f(y,i) = \min \{ j>i : A[j]=y \}.$$

Similarly, we're going to build a map $g$ defined by

$$g(y,i) = \min \{j<i : A[j]=y \}.$$

(We'll also build a set of inverted indices that, given $x$, enables us to enumerate all indices where $x$ appears in $A$.)

Note that these maps $f,g$ help us compute the distance function $d$ efficiently.  In particular,

$$d(x,y) = \min \{ f(y,i)-i : A[i]=x \} \cup \{ i-g(y,i) : A[i]=x \},$$

which can be computed with $r$ evaluations of $f$ and $r$ evaluations of $g$.  Consequently, given $x$, we'll be able to find the value $y$ that maximizes $d(x,y)$ using $rN$ evaluations of $f,g$, by simply trying all possibilities for $y$.

We're going to use the preprocessing to arrange things so we can evaluate $f,g$ at an input of our choice in $O(\lg L)$ time.  How do we do that?

Unfortunately, storing $f$ explicitly would take $NL$ space, which is too much.  Fortunately, there is a lot of redundancy in $f$: there are long ranges of indices $i,i+1,\dots,i'$ such that $f(y,i)=f(y,i+1)=\dots=f(y,i')$.  This is going to help us represent $f$ more compactly.  Similarly for $g$.

In particular, we'll store $f(y,\cdot)$ as an interval tree: whenever we have an interval $[i,i']$ such that $f(y,i)=f(y,i+1)=\dots=f(y,i')=\alpha$, then we add a single interval to the tree with the mapping $[i,i'] \to \alpha$.  In this way, $f$ is stored as $N$ different interval trees.  It is possible to show that the total number of leaves, across all of these interval trees, is at most $L+N=O(L)$ (in particular, the tree for $f(y,\cdot)$ has at most $r'+1$ leaves, where $r'$ counts the number of occurrences of $y$ in $A$).  If we store these trees as balanced binary trees, their height will be upper-bounded by $O(\lg L)$.  Consequently, the total amount of space needed to store these trees is $O(L \lg L)$.  You can also show how to generate these trees in $O(L \lg L)$ time.  Finally, evaluating $f$ at a point of your choice amounts to a stabbing query in the corresponding interval tree, which takes $O(\lg L)$ time.  This shows how to achieve the time complexity quoted in the first sentence of my answer.

---

As an optimization, if $x$ appears in $A$ more than $L/(N \lg L)$ times, you can answer the query in $O(L)$ time using a standard linear scan (skipping the above cleverness).  Of course, you can detect quickly which values of $x$ occur that often by using the inverted indices built during preprocessing.

With this idea, we get a scheme that requires $O(L \lg L)$ preprocessing and lets us answer each subsequent query in $O(\min(L, rN \lg L))$ time, where $r$ counts the number of times that the queried value occurs in $A$.